# Is there a way to 'pipe-together' slots in nested components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I'm developing an enhanced popper.js for Vue and I'm about to give it some additional functionality. This is how the very (child) component looks like:

```
 <popper>
   <div :is="tag" class="popper">
     {{ content }}
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" slot="reference">
     Reference Element
   </button>
 </popper>
```

As you can see, for it to work it requires defining reference element right beneath the ".popper" div with a slot="reference" attribute.

**Question**:

How to turn my *enhanced-popper* component into a re-usable entity, aka be able to pass slotted data indirectly - from
`<enhanced-popper> //referenced element// </enhanced-popper>` so that it has the slot="reference" attribute inside the child (popper.js-based) component?

**What did not work**:

Employing slots and having the attribute in a component passed in by the parent component does not yield desired results, as it does not get rendered at all.

```
  <popper>
   <div :is="tag" class="popper">
    {{ content }}
   </div>
   <slot></slot>
 </popper>
```

To ensure having the attribute out there I also tried to replace said button in the child component with a **named slot inside a slot** and go like this in my *enhanced-popper*:

```
<slot name="reference">
 <slot></slot>
</slot>
```

That way the first slotted component *has* the attribute - and it **almost** works, but since there are two "slot-layers" (no idea how to call it), the referenced component is not the first one as a child, and popper gets mis-positioned.

Cheers,
Paco

Comment: Can you provide a link to whatever `popper` is?